# How does Fancybox determine the next image in a gallery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How does fancybox determine the 'next' or 'previous' image in a gallery?

I have a page with photos on it arranged in vertical columns and want to understand fancybox's behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancybox selects all of the links on images in the DOM, ordered by your CSS selector.

**upd: sample**

```
<h1> gallery 1</h1>
<a href="urltodetail1.jpg" rel="gallery1"><img src="thumb1.jpg></a>
<a href="urltodetail2.jpg" rel="gallery1"><img src="thumb2.jpg></a>
<a href="urltodetail3.jpg" rel="gallery1"><img src="thumb3.jpg></a>

<h1> gallery 2 </h1>
<a href="urltodetail4.jpg" rel="gallery2"><img src="thumb4.jpg></a>
<a href="urltodetail5.jpg" rel="gallery2"><img src="thumb5.jpg></a>
<a href="urltodetail6.jpg" rel="gallery2"><img src="thumb6.jpg></a>

$("a[rel=gallery1],a[rel=gallery2]").fancybox();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PfaXm/

Comment: Is there a way to construct separate galleries?

Comment: Interesting I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: fancybox select by rel parameter in tag

Comment: $("a[rel=gallery1],a[rel=gallery2]").fancybox();

Comment: Does it have to use the 'rel' parameter? I have a fancybox that uses `$('.photos').fancybox()`. But it seems to have each individual photo in its own gallery.

Answer (score -1):

Fancybox groups galleries together by using the 'rel' attribute on elements targeted with .fancybox().

You can specify multiple galleris by using different 'rel' values.

Your gallery will appear in the same order as it is in jQuery's selection.